# Creating a C# Portable Class Library using command line csc.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-7, dll

I have not found any information on how to do this, or even if it's possible at all.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e13syb43

does not mention anything about building a portable class library, and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

does not mention anything about a command line interface.

Has anyone else tried to do this and found a solution/found it to be impossible?

Comment: Any library that uses the PCL is portable if it doesn't itself depends on platform implementation details introduced by pinvoke or COM dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building portable libraries via the command-line is possible, you just need to pass the correct framework references. These determine what platforms you will support.

First, is the reason you want to do this via the command-line because you don't have Visual Studio Pro? If so, it gets a little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would build csproj with MSBuild from command line instead of manually calling csc.exe.

On other hand the project seems to be set of assemblies - you should be able to give correct set of references (may also need to disable default libraries) via csc command line and build by hand.

Comment: I'm probably missing something entirely, but don't I need to target a particular version (2.0/3.0/3.5/4.0) and platform (full? compact? WP7?) when i build the dll using csc.exe? Or is that purely a MSBuild concern, and csc.exe's dlls can target any platform as long as they don't use unavailable libraries?

Comment: I don't know about particular "portable class library" solution, but normally building with MSBuild would produce the same output as you'd get building in VS. You can check what final libraries are referring when built from VS and see if you can get the same output via CSC/MSBuild.

Comment: @LiHaoyi You can only use portable class libraries on the 4.0 framework and above (4.5).  And since VS2010 has a template for it, why does it HAVE to be built at the command line, if I might ask?

Comment: I don't *have* to build it from the command line, i suppose, but it would work nicely with all my other tools, which are command line based.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx will take you which supporting assemblies can go into your dll, or where it can be deployed.

http://videojugpages.com/pages/610-Microsoft-Visual-C-Express-Setup This link will show you how to create your dlls at the command line.  This is pretty straightforward, and the general dll is no different from the portable type, except in where it can be deployed and on what it can depend.  Hope this helps.