# PCL DomCompiler Portable Class Library output

Tags: c#

I have below code snippet in one of my projects, which outputs a .dll from a given .cs file.

Now, I would love to output a portable class library instead of a standard library, yet have no idea how to change the output type.

I read the output type is just part of the .csproj, but I don't have a .csproj with this way of compiling to .dll.

```
    CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
    cp.OutputAssembly = "myassemblyname.dll";
    cp.GenerateInMemory = false; 
    cp.IncludeDebugInformation = true; 
    CompilerResults cr = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, new String[] { "MySourceFile.cs", codeFile });

    if(cr.Errors.Count > 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Errors building {0}", cr.PathToAssembly);
        foreach(CompilerError ce in cr.Errors) {
            Console.WriteLine("  {0}", ce.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Source {0} built into {1} successfully.", codeFile, cr.PathToAssembly);
}
```

Anyone have an idea howto instruct CSharpCodeProvider to output a Portable Class Library (PCL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423571/creating-a-c-sharp-portable-class-library-using-command-line-csc-exe) answer, you should just [pass the right assembly references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.referencedassemblies%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `CompilerParameters` and [set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.generateexecutable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `CompilerParameters.GenerateExecutable` property to false to generate dll.

To figure out the right references, you can build PCL via IDE and just look to Output window.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we switched this particular project's build method where it now just follows a .csproj. But our tests with adding the correct CompilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies seemed to work, so marked as answer.

20:20-hindsight-remark: Generating the code and asking build to compile a project does seem less of a headache now.. pointy clicky interfaces aren't so bad after all.